# Eloquent select specific columns

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to select specific columns using Laravel's Eloquent but I am having some issues. I just want to SELECT quantity, prices from prices. I have tried

```
$prices = Price::select(array('quantity', 'price'))->whereMonthAndYearAndType($month,$year,'cpi')
    ->with(array('product'=>function($query){ $query->select('id','name'); }))
    ->with(array('market'=>function($query){ $query->select('id','name'); }))->get();
```

but I am getting `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Can you show the exact error message, with the stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in your code snippet that would produce that error. However, I suspect you are getting the error when you are trying to access fields on the eager loaded `product` or `market` relationships without checking for their existence.

A common problem with specifying select statements and eager loading relationships is that the local and foreign keys usually get left out. However, these are the values that Laravel uses to match up all the related models, so they need to be selected, as well.

If price belongsTo a product and price belongsTo a market, then you also need to select the prices.product_id and prices.market_id fields. If price hasOne product or price hasOne market, then you'll need to select the prices.id field, and the corresponding foreign keys on the eager loaded relationships (products.price_id or markets.price_id).

Though, even once this is resolved, it is still a good idea to check to make sure the related record exists before trying to access it. In a hasOne/belongsTo relationship, if the related record doesn't exist, the relationship property will be NULL. If you try to access a field on NULL, you'll get the error you're seeing.